# Devise an experiment to verify that get item and set item are O(1)O(1) for dictionaries

Tags: python

so i am trying to write a code to verify that get item and set item are O(1) for dictionaries in Python  , but i get the following error (THE CODE IS BELOW THE ERROR) , Please assist me where possible i don't see anything wrong with the syntax:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "D:/MyPC/Python/python learning/review/2_11_Programming_Assignment"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/MyPC/Python/python learning/review/2_11_Programming_Assignment", line 25, in <module>
    GetItem2 = timeit.Timer("aDict.get(newItem)",  "from__main__ import aDict")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\timeit.py", line 128, in __init__
    compile(setup, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 1
    from__main__ import aDict
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## MY CODE

```
import timeit
import random

GetItem1 = timeit.Timer("aDict.get(someitem)","from __main__ import aDict")
GetItem2 = timeit.Timer("aDict.get(newItem)",  "from__main__ import aDict")
GetItem3 = timeit.Timer("aDict.get(Itemfive)", "from__main__ import aDict")

SetItem1 = timeit.Timer("aDict.set(someItem)", "from __main__ import aDict")
SetItem2 = timeit.Timer("aDict.set(newItem)", "from __main__ import aDict")
SetItem3 = timeit.Timer("aDict.set(Itemfive)", "from __main__ import aDict")

aDict = {'someItem': 2, 'otherItem': 20,'newItem': 400, 'nextItem': 2000, 
'Itemfive': 900}

print "GetItem1 : %s " % (GetItem1.timeit(100)), "millseconds"
print "GetItem1 : %s " % (GetItem2.timeit(100)), "millseconds"
print "GetItem1 : %s " % (GetItem3.timeit(100)), "millseconds"

print "SetItem1 : %s " % (SetItem1.timeit(100)), "millseconds"
print "SetItem1 : %s " % (SetItem2.timeit(100)), "millseconds"
print "SetItem1 : %s " % (SetItem3.timeit(100)), "millseconds"
```

Comment: Edit your question to format the error traceback message the same way you formatted the code.

Comment: `from__main__ import aDict` You need a space between `from` and `__main__`.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: I added some space, how ever i get the error "global variable someitem not recorgnised" ,then i replaced the key with the value and it worked for the aDict.get but for the aDict.set it say dict doesn't have attribute set , can some explain to me why it's working with value and not the key and why aDict.set is not working

Comment: Also i got these values for aDict.get : GetItem1 : 3.32679064506e-05  millseconds
GetItem2 : 2.97287674665e-05  millseconds
GetItem3 : 4.17618400125e-05  millseconds.....the values look very different does that mean get is not O(1) for dictionaries?